# Jenkins Per Slave Pipeline Build Enforcement

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to find a way to ensure that an entire pipeline completes on a specific executor without allowing other jobs to be run on that executor:

my pipeline essentially looks like:

Build -> Deploy -> API testing -> selenium testing

as we have multiple teams, all running multiple paralell pipelines i want to ensure that on a per slave basis all builds complete in the pipeline  before any others begin

Is anyone aware of a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [Locks and Latches](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin) plugin that can help you enforce this by assigning a lock to the relevant pipeline.
I have never tried your setup, but it might work.
Also, consider restricting the number of executors on the slave to 1, so only a single pipeline can "fit in".

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Setting the number of executors to 1 does not solve this problem, unfortunately. Consider this scenario:
1- Queue up pipeline A (build job A gets added)
2- Build job A finishes, queues up deploy job A
3- In the meantime, pipeline B gets queued (build job B gets added)
4- Deploy job A finishes, queues up testing A
5- Next job executes, which is build job B (should be testing A)

There needs to be some sort of logic to say "don't run any other job until the pipeline is finished" but I can't find a plugin that does this... Locks and Latches says it's obsolete?